# Bash script error using while and case

Tags: bash, centos5

first time asking a question here and still learning bash, so bear with me.

I made a main screen using while and case, it was supposed to work but it's not and I don't know where I made a mistake.

```
while [ $WH!=5 ]
do

echo "Choice menu:"
echo "          1) Option 1"
echo "          2) Option 2"
echo "          3) Option 3"
echo "          4) Option 4"
echo "          5) End script"
echo -n "Choose an option: "
read $OP

case $OP in
        1)
            # code;;

        2)
            # more code;;

        3)
            # more code;;

        4)
            # even more code;;

        5)
            echo "Thank you for testing this script!"
            $WH=5;;
esac
done
```

No matter what I put in `$OP`, the script keeps repeating the choice menu until I cancel it. I tried moving while and using `$OP` as the condition, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: It has to be `read OP`, not `read $OP`.

Comment: The `while` condition is incorrect, too (needs spaces around `!=`) - https://www.shellcheck.net/ will tell you things like that.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: By the way, have a look at the [`select`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-select) statement to build simple menus like this.

Comment: Replace `$WH=5` by `WH=5` and `!"` by `"!` and `read $OP` by `read OP`.

Comment: Technically, `read $OP` is not incorrect; what happens is `$OP`, unquoted and expanding to an empty string, causes `read` to put the answer in `REPLY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple issues in your script:-

1. `while` construct needs to be `while [ "$WH" != 5 ]`. Remember to double-quote all your shell variables.
2. The `read` command should be `read OP`
3. The `case` constructs need to atleast one line with a ending `;;`
4. The final assignment statement should be `WH=5` and not `$WH=5`

Use https://www.shellcheck.net to debug such trivial issues.

Comment: Some general rules: use `$` to get variables' values, *not* when setting their values; use double-quotes around variable references (`"$WH"` instead of `$WH`); and spaces matter a huge amount in shell (e.g. around `!=`). Oh, and one more: it's best to use lowercase variable names, do avoid conflicts with the variables that have special meaning to the shell and/or other programs (those are all caps).